# Tweepy API Live Stream (Two-separate words back to back) - Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I'm searching for separate words used back to back in a tweets, but it's resulting with tweets that have both words in one tweet (although not used in the correct form --- e.g. " Apple Watch " comes back as something like "@JohnDoe - I watch tv and eat an apple")

Code I'm currently using is as followed:

```
live_stream.filter(track = ("apple watch"))
```

I've also tried:

```
    live_stream.filter(track = ("\"apple watch\""))
```

Both have not worked for the task at hand. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a post-processing step on the output of the filter to get only what you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API doesn't support exact matching in this manner, unfortunately.

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters

> Exact matching of phrases (equivalent to quoted phrases in most search engines) is not supported.

The way to do it is as suggested by rbierman - retrieve the tweets and drop the ones that don't have the exact phrase, e.g., something along the lines of:

```
search_track = "apple watch"
retained tweets = [tweet for tweet in retrieved_tweets if search_track in tweet]
```